# Jaxb - Ignore unknown Attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a parent class which contains an enum "ActionType".

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Action")
public class ActionDto {
[...] ActionType type;
}
```

and some child-classes which extends ActionDto and have more special attributes like password (the LoginDto).

It's a server-client-connection.
I want to send some data from my client to my server. So I serialize it (I use Jaxb)
and deserialize it to an ActionDto-object.

An example for a LoginDto-Object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Action>
<type>LOGIN</type>
<password>Testpassword</password>
</Action>
```

I get an error if I want to deserialize it to an ActionDto-object - I think it's caused by the password-attribute. Can I make the Jaxb-unmarshaller ignore those unknown attributes?

Is there an other possibility to unmarshal it directly to my LoginDto-Object (The server receives just a xml-String, I don't know the special type) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default a JAXB implementation will ignore unknown elements.  If it is throwing an exception the default `ValidationEventHandler` has been replaced on the `Unmarshaller`.  You will need to replace the one that with one that is less sensitive.